# Displaying multi image from array with CarrierWave in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, carrierwave

I have a post with Thumbnail and Attachment. I'm using CarrierWave gem and it looks like uploading works. I can see the files in public/uploads folder and I can see the array in DB, but when it comes to listing in the view, it won't display the images but file names. What am I missing? I can display the thumb image as seen.

```
<%= image_tag @post.image_url.to_s %>

<% @post.attachment.each do |attachment| %>
  <%= image_tag attachment.url.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

[image]

It looks like it is adding this **%5B%22** and **%22%5D** that messes the correct path.

[image]

It looks like the Array doesn't loop.

```
<%= @post.attachment.count %>
```

returns

```
1
```

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I need to convert my String db field to String Array.